# Parsing pairs of a number or number range

Tags: c++, parsing, regex

I need to process an array of number pairs. Here are the constraints on the pairs:

1. The second item may be missing, in this case 0 will be used as second item - - `38` is the same as `38,0`
2. The pair items may be a number, or a range - `149,0`, `149,[3,7]`, `[5,9],11`, `[3,6],[2,9]`, `[4,8]`
3. The range may be inclusive or exclusive - `[8,11]`, `[3,9)`, `(4,10]`
4. There may be any number of spaces between items - `[ 3 , 6 ]`
5. The second item may be `>=0`, this is the same as bullet #1 - `36, >=0`

Why do I need the ranges? If I have, say, `149,[3,5]`, then I need to have 3 pairs - `149,3`, `149,4`, `149,5`. If I have `[8,10]`, then the pairs are `8,0`, `9,0`, `10,0`. You get the idea.

I wrote a regex to get the items from the input. I think regex is not the best choice here, maybe I'll change it. Here's my program:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

using intRange = std::pair<int, int>;
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs;

intRange getRange(const std::string &value1, const std::string &value2, const std::string &value3)
{
    if (value1.length())
        return intRange(std::stoi(value1), std::stoi(value1));

    if (value2.length() && value3.length())
    {
        const short startIncrement = value2.front() == '(' ? 1 : 0;
        const short endDecrement = value3.back() == ')' ? 1 : 0;

        // remove the parentheses
        std::string val2 = value2, val3 = value3;
        val2.replace(0, 1, std::string{});
        val3.pop_back();

        return intRange(std::stoi(val2) + startIncrement, std::stoi(val3) - endDecrement);
    }

    return {};
}

bool parseRange(const std::string &input)
{
    pairs.clear();

    static const std::regex rx{ R"numrange(\s*(?:(\s*\d+\s*)|([\[\(]\s*\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+\s*[\]\)]))(?:,\s*(?:(\d+\s*)|\s*([\[\(]\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+\s*[\]\)])|(\s*>\s*=\s*0\s*)))?\s*)numrange" };

    std::smatch matches;
    if (std::regex_match(input, matches, rx))
    {
        // if 1st (4th) match group exists, first (second) item is a single number
        // if 2nd and 3rd (5th and 6th) match groups exist, first (second) item is a range
        // if neither 4th nor 5th and 6th groups exist, then second item isn't specified, and default value (0) is used 
        auto firstRange = getRange(matches[1], matches[2], matches[3]);
        auto secondRange = getRange(matches[4], matches[5], matches[6]);

        // save all pairs
        for (auto first = firstRange.first; first <= firstRange.second; ++first)
            for (auto second = secondRange.first; second <= secondRange.second; ++second)
                pairs.emplace_back(first, second);
    }
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> inputs = {
        "38",
        "149,0",
        "149,[3,7]",
        "[5,9],11",
        "[3,6],[2,9]",
        "[4,8]",
        "[3,9)",
        "(4,10]",
        "[ 3 , 6 ]",
        "36, >= 0"
    };

    for (const auto &input : inputs)
    {
        if (parseRange(input))
        {
            std::cout << "input: " << input << '\n';
            for (const auto &pair : pairs)
                std::cout << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << '\n';
            std::cout << "-------------------\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error occurred.";
            return -1;
        }
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I think there is room for improvement for this code. Please let me know where I can improve. Thanks.

Comment: You say you need to process an *array* but seemingly match on a *string*. Is your original input an array but you flatten it into a string?

Comment: no it's an array, i just presented the method for a single element. i'm running a simple for loop on the array

Comment: Might be good to post the entire source code.

Comment: I've only omitted the for loop on the array. Another thought is that, I can have a separate regex for each of those cases. don't know if it's more efficient, though.

Comment: IMO It'd be nice to have the full code along with an example input as it makes it easier to reason about the code and architecture at large. See also [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: i've updated the post. this is still an excerpt from a larger program. anyways, it illustrates the idea.

Comment: @yuri did you have a chance to look at the code? i especially don't like the `getRange` method's body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering this question since it is unanswered. Hope, it would help:

Since your code is mainly about RegEx, which you'd most likely know that you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/Wdvkfa/4/) tool:

- Your original RegEx based on an exact match method takes 265 steps and 1ms to match your 10 inputs, which is good.

  ```
  \s*(?:(\s*\d+\s*)|([\[\(]\s*\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+\s*[\]\)]))(?:,\s*(?:(\d+\s*)|\s*([\[\(]\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+\s*[\]\)])|(\s*>\s*=\s*0\s*)))?\s*
  ```
- Sometimes, exact match may not be necessary, not sure about your case or if you might have certain boundaries, but maybe you could use a faster RegEx with a lower number of iterations, maybe something similar to [this](https://regex101.com/r/Wdvkfa/3), if you are not looking for an exact match, which is pretty fast and might match your 10 inputs with only 50 steps:

  ```
  ^[0-9\,\[\]\(\) >=]*$
  ```

The drawback of this method is that it is based on your input characters, i.e., numbers, <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd>, <kbd>)</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>>=</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

The code is pretty easy to read (apart from the monster regexp, but I'm pleased you used raw-string quoting rather than filling it with backslashes!).

Some (mostly stylistic) comments:

- If `getRange()` is an internal function, then give it internal linkage (`static` keyword, or an anonymous namespace).  If it's intended to be user-visible, then it could use better argument names (perhaps `only`, `first`, `last`?).
- I think that `if (!string.empty())` shows intent a little better than `if (string.length())`.
- Avoid calling `std::stoi(value1)` twice.
- Prefer to pass `pairs` to `parseRange()`, rather than working with a global variable.  Also it could be defined as `std::vector<intRange>`.
- The big regexp could be split into several strings so that it can occupy several shorter lines, just as we do with ordinary string literals.
- I'd invert the test so we can return early:

  ```
  std::smatch matches;
  if (!std::regex_match(input, matches, rx)) {
      return false;
  }

  // matched (rest of comment omitted)
  auto firstRange = getRange(matches[1], matches[2], matches[3]);
  auto secondRange = getRange(matches[4], matches[5], matches[6]);

  /* ... */

  return true;
  ```
- Generation of the result pairs could alternatively be done using `std::inner_product()`.  However, I think the nest of loops expresses it more clearly.
- You forgot to `#include <iostream>` in the test program (preventing it compiling here).
- `inputs` doesn't need to be a vector; it can be deduced (`auto const inputs`) as an initializer list.